# textarea is not displaying Java EE and HTML

Tags: java, html

I have a textarea which should display the contents of a .cfg file. my problem is when I run firebug and inspect the textarea I see the elements which are supposed to be present. otherwise my page shows nth.

String fileControllerF3 = getFileConfigurationF3(null);

```
            vVelocityContext.put("fileControllerF3", fileControllerF3);

            affichePage(vNomdePage, vContext, pRequest, pResponse,
                vVelocityContext, Constantes.EC_ADM_FICHIER_CONFIG_F3);

            return null;
        }


 private String getFileConfigurationF3(File fileF3) throws IOException {


        StringBuffer contents = new StringBuffer();

        try {

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:/transcoF3.cfg"));
        try {
            String line = null; 

            while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
            contents.append(line);
            contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            }
        }
        finally {
            input.close();
        }
        }
            catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


        return contents.toString();

}
```

Comment: <tr>
<td colspan="2">
<textarea  name="fileControllerF3" value="$fileControllerF3" cols="90%" rows="30"></textarea>
</tr>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your text between the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags, not in a `value` attribute.

Comment: I changed it to :
<textarea input name="fileControllerF3" readonly="true" cols="90%" rows="40""  value="$fileControllerF3"></textarea>

meaning I removed (type="textarea) BUT now the vaules are not being displayed(ofcourse they are there coz I can see them with firebug)!!

Comment: I think @Alohci means change it to <textarea input name="fileControllerF3" readonly cols=90%" rows="40">$fileControllerF3</textarea>